Cheap Amazon polaris connectors
Has anyone used these cheap Polaris type connectors from Amazon?
https://a.co/d/ctHvNCo
At $10 per connector, it would save me $60 on an unexpected junction i have to make.
Just a little hesitant to use cheap Amazon(if they are cheap vs inexpensive) on a new subpanel run. However this project is already proving more expensive than planned thanks to my quirky house.
Updated with more details:  I can't run conduit all the way to my main panel, so i have to switch from 2 2 2 4 MHF that i ran most of the way to 2 2 2 4 SER (AL) for the last 15'.

Updated:
Parts came in and actually have a UL listing. Now wondering if it's legit.


BUYER BEWARE
Anything that gets permanently installed in your electrical system needs to be either UL, ETL or similar (not CE - that means something in some places but not in the US, not TM - that's registered trademark, not FCC - that's (if valid...) about radio interference, not electrical safety) listed for safety. Exceptions can be made by your local jurisdiction for new/unusual situations. But if you install something not properly listed or approved and then something goes wrong, your insurance will not pay.
There is no indication on the Amazon page or on the extremely limited Airmont Products web site of any UL, ETL or similar listing. That's not a big deal for their fancy cover plates. But is critical for wire connectors, as even a good connector if used improperly can cause a fire, and a poor quality connector is, literally, playing with fire.
For a temporary external project - e.g., wiring up some temporary lighting or similar, it would probably be OK. But definitely not a good idea for a permanent installation.
Provide more information - wire size and other details - and there might be some other workarounds available short of true Polaris connectors. But even if it comes down to that, the cost just isn't that much overall.

Good news! Based on pictures together with online search, it looks product is UL listed after all. If that had been noted on the manufacturer web page or Amazon then this would have been much easier.

Doh. I should have thought about that. Thanks for pulling me into reality.  I can't run conduit all the way to my main panel, so i have to switch from 2 2 2 4 MHF that i ran most of the way to 2 2 2 4 SER (AL) for the last 15'.

Sometimes there is a cheap workaround using a disconnect box. But the cheapies (a) are usually 2, sometimes 3, rarely 4 wires and (b) typically max. out at 60A. You're in 90A land - Polaris type connectors are the normal solution.

Ok. Sounds like it is what it is. Yes, running 90amp service.

well the part came in with a legitimate looking UL listing. Going to try and do some research to see if it's legit

Looked it up, and it's legit
